# Mysql select first and second query

Tags: mysql, selection

I have a table that have

name
order_number
price
id

And records i.e.

```
 name = test
    order_number=1
    price=3
    id=555

    name=test2
    order_number=2 
price=2
    id=555

    name = test3
    order_number=1
    price=5
    id=556

    name = test4
    order_number=2
    price=12
    id=556
```

there are multiple inputs with same id, and order_number goes up to ten. I need to write a query that will compare order_number=1 and order_number=2 for same id and return compassion of them. IE price of order number 1 / price of order number 2  with same id. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   SELECT t1.price / t2.price
   FROM your_table t1, your_table t2
   WHERE t1.id = t2.id
   AND t1.order_number = 1
   AND t2.order_number = 2
```

Comment: They are in same table i mean on order number

Comment: Yes, in my query `t1` and `t2` are two instances of the same table `your_table`

Comment: I would give you 100 rep for this. I didn't saw your_table at first. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As a note, you can also do this with conditional aggregation instead of a `join`:

```
select id, (case when order_number = 1 then price end) / (case when order_number = 2 then price end)
from table t
group by id;
```

Comment: I will try your solution too.

Answer (score 0):

try it
select t1.price / t2.price from test11 t1,test11 t2 where t1.id=t2.id  and t1.order_number =1 and t2.order_number=2;